# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified?

Tags: docker

При выполнении команды с sudo в docker, появляется такое предупреждение:

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> ```
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
> #2) Think before you type.
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
> ```
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Вот содержимое файла:

```
FROM debian:jessie
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

# Добавлем пользователя node js
# RUN useradd -ms  --disabled-password --gecos /bin/bash node

RUN useradd -d /home/node -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -p node node
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node
WORKDIR /home/node
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN sudo usermod -a -G sudo node
```

Из-за чего это происходит и как использовать команду sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RUN sudo usermod -a -G sudo node
> ```

1. в данном случае вызов программы *usermod* вообще не нужен: он дублирует добавление пользователя `node` в группу `sudo`, которое произошло семью строчками выше при выполнении команды:

   ```
   useradd -d /home/node -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -p node node
   ```
2. а вызов программы *sudo* тем более не нужен — команды, перечисленные в директивах `run` в *dockerfile* и так выполняются от имени пользователя `root`.